# Обновление данных в таблице SQL

Tags: sql, update, таблицы

Мне нужно изменить данные тех, у кого в таблице номер начинается на 8495 и изменить его на 8499, но при попытке выполнить запрос происходит ошибка синтаксиса

```
update dbo.Читатели_запрос_PK set LEFT(контактный_телефон, 4) = 8499
where LEFT(контактный_телефон, 4) = 8495
```

Сообщение 156, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 1
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "LEFT".

Время выполнения: 2019-10-29T22:03:40.1421046+03:00

Comment: В части set слева от знака равно должно быть именно поле и ничего более. LEFT это функция, нельзя присвоить значение функции. так что пользуясь строковыми функциями вашего sql сконструируйте полное значение телефона и присвойте его полю, что то вроде `телефон='8499'+substr(телефон, 4, 7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как верно указали в комментариях, в части `SET` конструкции `UPDATE` ожидается имя обновляемого поля, а в части `WHERE` - условие, на соответствие которому будут проверяться строки бд. Таким образом, ваш запрос должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
UPDATE dbo.Читатели_запрос_PK SET контактный_телефон = '8499' + RIGHT(контактный_телефон, LEN(контактный_телефон) - 4)
WHERE LEFT(контактный_телефон, 4) = '8495'
```

Отмечу, что функции работы со строками в разных реализациях SQL отличаются и подстроку из номера телефона с 5-го символа можно получить разными способами.